# Treating an Oracle many to many table as a table instead of an association

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx

I'm trying to make a Web Project with Visual Studio 2012. I want to create an ADO.NET Entity data model with an Oracle DB.

In my databases, I have some tables named:

- X_TRVS
- X_MATERIAL
- X_TRVS_MATERIAL

This last is a table which only contains X_TRVS primary keys and X_MATERIAL primary keys. So it seems an association but it is a table. When I'm using the software "TOAD", I can see that it is considered as a table. But when I create my .edmx, this table doesn't appear and I think it is considered as an association.

How can I avoid this transformation or work with this association like a table?

Answer (score 1):

The table seems to be a join table in a many to many association. Therefore the EF designer collapses it to an association in the conceptual model. This results in just two classes in your program and each of those should have a collection navigation property with objects of the other type. This way you don't have to deal with an entity that exists in the database only to be able to express a many-to-many relationship but is not really necessary in the code where you can use collections to model the same concept.
Note - if you look at the store model in your edmx file the table should be stil there. Had the join table additional columns (not only keys) the designer wouldn't have converted it to an association because the table now has more data which would prevent it from being collapsed.

Comment: I just wanted to say this (as @Pawel mentioned) - good practice is for each table to have 4 standard columns - dateCreated, userCreated, dateModified, userModified. If your many-to-many table had those, you wouldn't be dealing now with your problem.

Comment: I have not mentioned having additional if this is not necessary and I don't necessarily think that having 4 standard columns for each table is a good practice. I only said that there might be additional columns in the join table (which would be kind of additional attributes/details of the association) and in this case the join table wouldn't be collapsed.

Comment: In a serious system, there is no way these 4 columns don't exist as auditing and tracking are always part of such system.

Comment: like for a dictionary/reference tables?

Comment: You mean look-up tables? Believe it or not, when look-up values are dynamically created by admin users, these records also tracked.